# The integral of the unit normal field over a closed surface

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

The integral of the unit normal field over a closed surface vanishes. [There's a simple proof based on the divergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631281/closed-surface-integral-of-the-surfaces-normal-vector). But is there a proof that "stays within the surface" (in other words, doesn't refer to objects in the ambient space) that would reveal the deeper geometric reason behind this fact?

Clarification in response to the comments: I'm not looking for an "intrinsic" proof, but a proof restricted to objects defined on the surface. For example, the [proof](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243098012_Surface_integral_of_Its_Mean_Curvature_Vector) of same statement for the mean curvature normal is of this kind.

Comment: The "normal field" is - as far as I remember - an extrinsic property using the ambient space itself.

Comment: Yes, but restricted to the surface.

Comment: How would you define the normal vector without reference to the ambient space?  How could you even state the theorem?  There doesn't seem to be any hope of giving an intrinsic proof of the theorem unless you can state it intrinsically.

Comment: In view of the proof, the deep geometric reason is that the surface is the boundary of a solid region in the ambient space. You could perhaps reformulate the question as how to recognize intrinsically that a manifold is the boundary of a solid region in a higher dimensional space.

Comment: That reformulation should be that the $2$-cycle represented by the closed surface is trivial in homology. But ultimately we're still applying Stokes's Theorem (abstractly) to deduce that a $2$-form on the surface has zero integral.

Comment: Presumably the "intrinsic" proof you reference proceeds by applying Stokes's Theorem in the other dimension, i.e., by showing that the $2$-form is exact (rather than by using $S=\partial \Omega$). We can do that in this case, too. Finding the flux of $\vec i$ across $S$ is integrating the $2$-form $dy\wedge dz$ over the surface, and this $2$-form is plainly exact.